# how to get the value from a dateTime picker and combo box and set it as a dateTime variable? In c#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, datetimepicker

I have a windows form in c# which the user has to pick a date from the DateTime picker and a time from the combo box. But how do i store them in the same DateTime variable?

Comment: If you're working in an IDE with intellisense, you can easily check the overloads of the DateTime constructor to see what you need to pass in. Otherwise, just look up the documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Can you explain why you need store the `DateTime` in the same variable?

Comment: I have an interface which only has one DateTime variable

Comment: Isn't time included in DateTimePicker control? why need to get time in combo box?

Comment: Thanks, I have now changed it so that the user can pick the date and time from the same DateTimePicker.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have two separate fields, the DateTime Picker returning a DateTime object (pickerValue) and the Combobox returning a string value (dropdownValue):

```
DateTime finalValue;            
try
{
    TimeSpan ddValue = TimeSpan.Parse(dropdownValue);
    finalValue = pickerValue.Date.AddTicks(ddValue.Ticks);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    //handle exception
    // most likely dropdownValue is not properly formatted timeString.
    finalValue = pickerValue.Date; //or however you would like to handle
}
```

Comment: finalValue cannot be set to null??

Comment: Hi, ive just tried this and the value that is return is 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM?

Comment: My bad... I swore I tested this and it worked...Give me a second

Comment: ok. so the issue with the returned value is that you ran into an exception, the finalValue does not get set, so its set to minimum date (I believe).

Comment: this try/catch block here is to catch exceptions that are thrown from the Timespan.Parse function.  if the returned value of dropdownValue is not valid, then it will throw an exception.  usually you can set a text/value pair to drop down lists, so set the value in the list item to a 24 hour clock, with seconds. 

i.e. for 10:35 PM the value would be "22:35:00"